# Tell knockout observable to rebind from source

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

If i was to have a textarea that is updated outside of a keydown event it is not rebinding my observable.

I tried calling `model.WrittenContent.valueHasMutated()` which refreshes the textarea ***not*** the observable.

I am using a what i perceive to be a hack to do this currently, but would prefer not to do it this way...

```
model.WrittenContent($('#my-input').val());
```

can i get knockout to re-evaluate the value of the textarea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that whatever you're doing to update the textarea isn't causing the textarea to issue any sort of event that the bindings are listening to, so Knockout has no way of knowing that it needs to update any observables.

Probably about the best you can do is something like

```
$('#my-input').change();
```

which should generate a `change` event that the bindings can recognize, assuming that the `valueUpdate` parameter is set to `change` (as it is by default). This, BTW, is also what you have to do if you're binding to a non-form element with `contenteditable` set, since those don't generate `change` events by themselves.

Comment: Yeah i think you are right, i'm using a pagedown editor (like here on stack overflow) but clicking bold italics etc is not updating the observable despite changing the textbox value.